# How can I simply store URL data between UIViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I need to transfer **NSURL** data to target **UIViewController** for **UIWebView**. How can I do it to load required url from **ViewDidLoad** of target view? I am using storyboard, ARC, iOS5.

Comment: to clarify, which way are you trying to send info? Sending URL from ViewController to WebView, or sending URL from WebView to ViewController?

Comment: From main ViewController to ViewController which contains UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a delegate to send the URL from `UIViewController` to `UIWebView`.

In your webview create a delegate property:

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) (id) delegate;
```

Synthezize as normal. Then in the webviews `viewDidLoad` method write:

```
self.someWebViewURLProperty = self.delegate.someURLPropertyFromUIController;
```

Now set the delegate in your ViewController. In your `UIViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method write:

```
self.webViewProperty.delegate = self;
```

It may seem a bit more involved than using prepareForSegue, but both methods are valid. I prefer delegation as its a standard cocoa design pattern.

Comment: That works. I added self.WebView.delegate = self; and everything worked fine.

Comment: awesome! Glad it worked. Delegation is a really powerful design method - I use it all the time.